# How to verify a method called when one of the method parameters are generated in the object under test in mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm calling a method on a mock in a service I am testing.

The mock is a class for updating database data, I want to verify that the update method is called.
The code looks like this:

```
verify(updateLockedAccountStatusMock, times(1)).update(1, 3, true, new Date());
```

I know this can't work, since the `Date` object that is passed into the mock in the class under test is generated in the class just before the method is called. I also know that I can't call `any()` here unless I call `any()` for every parameter. I'd rather not do that as the same method is called elsewhere in the code.
Is there a way to handle cases like this? Or is it simply a matter of passing in `any()` for every parameter and verifying the amount of times it's called?
In particular I want to see that the third parameter `true` is correct, but the date is the only one I don't really care about at the moment.

Comment: You can use `any()` for one argument and other matchers (such as [`eq`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq(T))) for the other arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any()` for one argument and other matchers (such as [`eq`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq(T))) for the other arguments.

```
verify(updateLockedAccountStatusMock, times(1)).update(eq(1), eq(3), eq(true), any());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any method from `ArgumentMatchers`:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

class A {
    private final B b;

    A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    void aMethod(int x) {
        b.bMethod(x, new Date());
    }
}

class B {
    void bMethod(int x, Date d) {}
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;
    @Mock
    private B b;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        a.aMethod(5);
        verify(b).bMethod(ArgumentMatchers.eq(5), ArgumentMatchers.any(Date.class));
    }
}
```

As an aside: Have a class which calls `new Date()` in the midst of other code is a smell. How will you test date dependant code with a range of dates?

You should create a simple `DateProvider`, which you can mock, i.e.:

```
@Component // assuming Spring DI
class DateProvider {
    Date getDate() {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Your tests mock this class and return whatever date you like.